# VBA Sigma Formula

Tags: excel, vba, algebra

I got a task in university, but have no idea how to solve it. Need help.

[image: task]

Tried to solve it with cycle, but dont think that its right.

```
For k = 1 To 10
    For i = 1 To k
    n! = 1 * 2 * n
    S = S * S * sin (2i + 10) / n!
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood properly, it should be something like this:

```
Sub test()
Dim i As Long
Dim k As Long
Dim Numerator As Double
Dim Result As Double


For k = 1 To 10 Step 1
    Numerator = 0
    For i = 1 To k Step 1
            Numerator = Numerator + Sin(2 * i + 10)
    Next i
    Result = Result + Numerator / Application.WorksheetFunction.Fact(k)
Next k

Debug.Print Result

End Sub
```